# Postgres13 logical replication degrading slowly

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-performance, master-slave-replication, postgresql-13

We're halfway through a postgres upgrade (from 11 to 13) and have run into a pretty unusual blocker, being that our 13 logical replica can't seem to keep up with changes from our 13 master.  For illustration purposes:

```
PG11 current master 
-- logical replication to -> PG13 new master 
   -- logical replication to -> PG13 Read replica
   -- physical replication to -> PG13 Failover
```

Replication to the new master seems to work fine, and keeps up with volume, however replication to the PG13 Read replica seems to keep consistently falling further and further behind (got up to 500G lag before I gave up) and I can't figure out why.

Things I've tried:

- Rebuilding the lagging replica (works initially, then falls behind and steadily degrades)
- Increasing disk IOPS on the replica (no effect).  I may need to adjust PG settings too to take advantage?
- Decreasing the Shared buffer size (referenced from another post)
- Checked on iowait, generally @ 90% idle.
- Increased instance CPU (generally pointless due replication being single-threaded after the initial hydration
- Increased instance RAM (no effect)

I'm generally confused because the new master is replicating fine.  There are some key differences between master 13 and replica 13 however:

- Replication for master is same region, for the replica it's cross-region
- The master has 0 BAU load while we are doing the migration.  The replica is subject to validation load (but not BAU load).
- The replica is getting LESS data than the Master.  Master is receiving an ALL TABLES publication.

I figure the cross-region component of the replication shouldn't really matter.  It would manifest in lag, but not in gradual deterioration of the connection.  I also figure the issue isn't with the master, as it's writing WAL logs to drive without issue.

I'm not a DBA, so I'd bet there's a whole heap of stuff I could be looking at and tweaking.

In the event I can't fix the issue, I do have the option of driving our engineering teams to break apart the current publication into smaller ones to increase throughput, but I can't get over the fact that our current PG11 instance is handling replication and serving read queries just fine.

I'm about to go back to the drawing board and try a few other things, but any guidance at all or questions for additional information would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Resources that could be maxed out are network or I/O (CPU is unlikely).

Comment: Potentially network I guess.  IO seems fine (idle around 90%).  Just seems odd right? shouldn't data still be transferring, it's not like the volume would be an issue.